# Clear selected value after POST method

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I'm trying to make a web for 3 different reports. In the last 2 reports I need the user to specify 2 dates.

I would like a JavaScript function that triggers after the POST method is sent, so I can clear the user selection. First I tried to made it like you can see here: https://codepen.io/nahuelg90/pen/ZMjLgq . But the problem was that the data cleared before the POST method is sent, as you can see in the following function (is the same for `validateGenerados()`):

```js
function validateCierreAdmin() {

  var inicio = document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaInicio"].value;
  var fin = document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaFin"].value;
  if (inicio == "") {
    alert("Debe completar la fecha de inicio");
    return false;
  }
  if (fin == "") {
    alert("Debe completar la fecha de fin");
    return false;
  }
  if (inicio > fin) {
    alert("La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor a la de fin");
    return false;
  }

  $('#ticketsCierreAdminPop').slideFadeToggle();
  document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaInicio"].value = "";
  document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaFin"].value = "";
}
```

Comment: You can look at ajax for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply post the data first and clear after submitting.
use this .submit method

function validateCierreAdmin() {

```
  var inicio = document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaInicio"].value;
  var fin = document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaFin"].value;
  if (inicio == "") {
    alert("Debe completar la fecha de inicio");
    return false;
  }
  if (fin == "") {
    alert("Debe completar la fecha de fin");
    return false;
  }
  if (inicio > fin) {
    alert("La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor a la de fin");
    return false;
  }

 document.getElementsByTagName("form").submit();

  $('#ticketsCierreAdminPop').slideFadeToggle();
  document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaInicio"].value = "";
  document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"]["fechaFin"].value = "";
}
```

This method will submit your data first then it will clear the values.

Comment: I still need to trigger this function with onsubmit? or do I need to change the submit button?

Comment: no need to change the button,just call this function with onsubmit

Comment: I did ti but it seems that is deleting it befor is sent, because the .php is note getting any value from POST.

Comment: If complete the fields and run "document.forms["ticketsCierreAdminForm"].submit();" on the Chrome's console, it  gets me the result. But not if i do it on the onsubmit event.

Comment: okay , try to fire your event using onClick rather then onSubmit